# How to simulate a DC sine ripple in proteus

Tags: proteus

I am trying to simulate a DC sine ripple in proteus to emulate power supply noise and see how effective different power supply filtering will be but i could not find a simulation primitives for this The Sine Generator. The Sine Generator generates AC signal the offset also  does nothing that i can see off

[image]
[image]

Comment: Take your scope channels OFF AC coupling!  DC coupling should show you if there's really an offset.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Thank you ! that did the trick, please post you comment as an answer so i can mark it as an answer